# How to use a particular widget inside a ListView.builder in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to insert a widget inside a `ListView.builder`.

I tried creating a separate list and include it in the ListView but no results. I even tried nested `ListView.builder`.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.

```
ListView.builder(
itemCount: dataLists.lists.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Widget(dataLists.lists[index]);
  },
);`
```

Answer (score 0):

create a listOfWidget, use `statefullWidget` and any changes on widget will reflect to the UI.  make changes inside `setState()` .

here is full widget

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DynamicListView extends StatefulWidget {
  DynamicListView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DynamicListViewState createState() => _DynamicListViewState();
}

class _DynamicListViewState extends State<DynamicListView> {
  List<Widget> widgets = List.generate(
    4,
    (index) => Container(
      height: 50,
      color: index % 2 == 0 ? Colors.cyanAccent : Colors.pinkAccent,
      child: Text("item $index"),
    ),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: widgets.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => widgets[index],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            widgets.add(Container(
              height: 60,
              color: Colors.amber,
              child: Text("new Widget"),
            ));
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```